# How do I relate a text field from a node to a Commerce Order?

Tags: views, commerce

I have a View displaying content 'X'... it has a text field called Order_Number, which may or may not contain a value which would reference the order_number field in a Commerce Order.

I would like to be able to display a field from a Commerce Order if X:order_number matches Commerce:Order Number.

Unfortunately, no Commerce fields are available in the Relation section of Advanced. I assume this is because the field is NOT an Entity Reference, right? Also, this content type already contains lots of nodes so I can't change the field type anyway. And finally, the field X:Order_Number is not an Entity Reference and cannot be because, as I said, this field will often be blank. So it's an outer join.

So, is there a way to custom join (relate?) the X:order_number field to the Commerce Order:order_number field so that if there is a match, the View will display a related field from Commerce Orders?

OR put another way: How do I get fields from Commerce Order to appear as candidates in the Relation list without an Entity Reference field?

Comment: *"cannot be because, as I said, this field will often be blank."* This statement is simply false, because you can have optional entity reference fields, and you can leave them blank if they are optional.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not clear then on the nomenclature. It seems like a Commerce Order is a special case: You have to use a View in the 'Mode' field, right? I created a View to return the Order ID. Now what seems to happen is that, if the value one enters is invalid, the value is not saved in the field... that's bad for us. We need the value to match if it does or leave it as is. We're importing from an old spreadsheet and the data isn't normalised. TIA.

Comment: I was commenting only on the blank entity reference part. Contrray to what you wrote, field itself can be left blank, and Commerce is no special case as far as I know. But this is far from being an answer to your question - the rest is outside of my experience and I have no environment to test.

Comment: Thanks. I did some experimentation with the various Entity Reference widget field types to get this. This is one of those times I just wish I could enter a SQL Query or some PHP directly.